# Request more attributes values from the server(Thingboard-Gateway)

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

is it possible to request more attributes (shared attributes) values from server, when the MQTT Gateway APIs are used?
Unfortunately in the thingsboard MQTT Gateway API Reference only for one attribute
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/gateway-mqtt-api/

Comment: I am wondering about the same issue.